# How can i fill numbers to the boxes from database?

Tags: c#, html, css, sql, asp.net

i have a table and i want to fill boxes with OrderedID like that;

```
        PlayerId   Name         OrderedID 
        4          Alex Nice        1
        6          David Cup        3
        7          John Fun         2
        10         Mary Hill        6
        11         Michal Ola       5
        12         Henry Ford       4
```

[image]

how can i do that with asp.net?   My codes and result down.

```
SqlConnection yol = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
        yol.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from players order by OrderedID", yol);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
 int k = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
            {
                sb.Append(dt.Rows[j][2].ToString());
                sb.Append(".   "+dt.Rows[j][1].ToString() + "   ");
                k++;
            }


            treeview.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(sb.ToString()));
        }
```

here is my result. help me please.

[image]

Comment: I don't understand your problem. I see your current result. How should the result look like?

Comment: @cSteusloff  i want to make similar this. https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWV59.png
The players will be ordered like a pyramid. 1, 2-3, 4-5-6, 7-8-9-10 .....

Comment: You are adding a new node to your tree for each record you are adding to your string. Looks like you need something like a) another variable to count the "level" of the tree and b) another for loop to build a new string for each level THEN add a new node. Hopefully that makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

Its not entirely 1 to 1 with your code, but I think its adaptable to your situation.

I made a similar snippet in a fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mNZMFR).

The "special sauce" I came up with is this algorithm:

```
int skip = 0;
int take = 1;
int addedCount = 0;

do{
    sb.AppendLine(string.Join(" ", players.Skip(skip).Take(take).Select(x => $"{x.Order}) {x.Name}")));
    addedCount += take;
    skip += take;
    take += take + 1;           
}
while(addedCount < players.Count);
```

I cannot reproduce databases entirely in .NET Fiddle so my snippet uses "Player" objects, but if you substitute for your DB rows/cols you should be good.  There maybe better ways of looping through this (this was just my quick 2 min attempt), but this *should* help give you some direction.

Comment: your solution is good. How can i do it with c# 5.0 and asp.net.  it was give me error in this line    $"{x.Order}) {x.Name}")));

Comment: You can concatenate the strings: `x => x.Order + ") " + x.Name`, or use string.format: `x => string.Format("{0}) {1}", x.Order, x.Name")`

Comment: thank you very much. working fine :).   i have a small problem now.  string.Format("<a runat=server class=link id=link{2} href=detail.aspx?id={2}>  {0}.{1} </a>", x.Order, x.Name, x.ID))));
-------------------
if id==link13  <a class=link2> how can i do that?

Comment: I’m unsure what you’re asking exactly, can you try to clarify more?

Comment: I want to find one of the generated links and change the style. when i run HtmlAnchor findlink = (HtmlAnchor) this.FindControl("link13");
findlink.Style.Add("background-color","red");
but it gives me Null referances error.

Comment: @davuttemel that problem is not inside the scope of this question.  I would recommend asking a new question specific to that problem so that others may find it later and get help from it.